# I can't export materials or textures

Tags: texturing, materials, export

I'd like to create models for Unity asset store and so on, but I can't even export materials or textures, not just to Unity, but in general. In the picture below I tried exporting a simple object that has a material on it into 1. FBX and into 2. 3DS formats and then importing them right back. Neither worked, 3ds even didn't export geometry correctly.

[image]

Earlier today I also tried exporting a texture (simple table object with a texture on it, uv unwrapped), but I got the same result, so what am I doing wrong?

When I export objects with a simple program like Sketchup, the textures on the models appear instantly once I put the objects in Unity engine, no need to even assign anything, just drop it in the Unity project folder and that's it. I also managed to export a 3ds (or obj, can't remember) file from Sketchup to Blender, with textures, and everything worked perfectly fine, but I am missing something about Blender that's preventing me from exporting me anything other than geometry...

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: It's not a duplicate obviously since that one was asked a year ago and I don't even use unreal engine. Anyway, I'm a total noob, but I know how to make some basic and even intermediate models, but I don't know how am I suppoose to export them. I would like to sell them on 3d trade sites in the future, but I don't know how they should look, like that gray FBX export or...? I'd prefer an answer to a link, I checked a dozen of threads already, but none really gave me a simple answer I'm looking for.